# Birt: how to deploy a report in production?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, birt

I have just prepared a report with bird using eclipse plugin. It works.
Now I have deployed a birt 4.4 viwer on a Tomcat7. It works.
Now I put my report.rptdesign file insider birt folder under webapps in tomcat.
It does not work.
Obviously because:

- the jdbc driver is encoded in report with full path that is obviously different from eclipse to tomcat;
- birt needs a "org.eclipse.datatools_workspacepath" configured in tomcat (why????)
- even if I configure above variable it complains about missing:
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/datatools/enablement/ibm/util/ClientUtil

Yes I have used standard jdbc source (not "for query builder" one).

I would like to ask stack overflow why is so bloody complicated (and not documented) putting in production a simple report that uses a mysql jdbc jar.

Can you help me?

Thanks,
Mario

Comment: When you purchase the higher end BIRT tool, it has more instructions and more help.  The people working on the free version spend more time improving the tool, than updating the instructions.

Comment: In this case I am not asking to receive for free an advanced/enterprise feature  but a basic thing that in 2014 should be common: the possibility to have two different configurations, one for development and one for production. Choosing to not document this can have as side effect that developers will choose another product. Anyway my question can be also read like this: since that feature is so common and I am not finding it maybe I am searching in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't understand all the question but I use birt with glassfish and jboss, you need to configure a JDBC in your server (I suppose you already have done that), then you have to change your Datasources erase all and use a JNDI URL with the name of your JDBC for example, if you create a datasource JDBC/test this is the JNDI url.
For the workspacepath I think this can be solved changing something in the birt war, go to META-INF and open the web.xml, then change this properties for another folders that have sufficient access permissions:

```
    <param-name>BIRT_VIEWER_WORKING_FOLDER</param-name>
    <param-name>BIRT_VIEWER_DOCUMENT_FOLDER</param-name>
    <param-name>BIRT_VIEWER_IMAGE_DIR</param-name>
    <param-name>BIRT_VIEWER_LOG_DIR</param-name>
```